# VirtualProtect and kernel32.dll - attempt to access invalid address

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, kernel32

I'm analyzing various modules loaded by the process. Unfortunately I'm not able to create the `kernel32.dll` memory snapshot although the function works properly with other modules (e.g. `ntddl.dll`). The problem is with the following code:

```
/* Copy code from memory  */
if (VirtualProtect((BYTE*)virtualAddress, sizeOfCode, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &flags) == 0) {
    std::cout << "VirtualProtect failed!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Virtual address: " << virtualAddress << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of code: " << sizeOfCode << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
```

The result of calling this code for `kernel32.dll` is:

```
Virtual address: 747d0000
Size of code: 6a000
Error code: 0x1e7
```

The error description says that:

```
ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS
487 (0x1E7)
Attempt to access invalid address.
```

I checked the process' memory map and kernel32.dll address is correct. What's the cause?

Comment: It is not proper code, you must call GetLastError() immediately.  The cout calls can easily modify the value since they use winapi calls as well.

Comment: The result is the same when `GetLastError()` is called right after `VirtualProtect`

Comment: kernel32.dll is a bit special. It would make some sense to stop you interfering with it - eg to prevent various injection attacks.

Comment: The same situation is with winspool.drv

Comment: just to say that when I wrote a debugger using the "Debugging Functions" API I got the same issue : these debugging functions allow you to create a user-mode debugger but not a kernel-mode debugger (I could not enter nor pause the process into kernel functions). thus, if I remember well, kernerl32.dll was debuggable&editable if I ran my code in administrator mode, but not ntdll.dll and many other nt*.dll files.
You can see the same fact when debugging a program with Visual C++ : it's doesn't let you enter in NT functions (even when stepping in assembler) because it is a user-mode debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty hard to verify that you got the address correct, it is unusually low.  I just wrote another program to test this.  It enumerates the regions in kernel32.dll and calls VirtualProtect() on them:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    HMODULE hmod = GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll");
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
    // Start at PE32 header
    SIZE_T len = VirtualQuery(hmod, &info, sizeof(info));
    assert(len > 0);
    BYTE* dllBase = (BYTE*)info.AllocationBase;
    BYTE* address = dllBase;
    for (;;) {
        len = VirtualQuery(address, &info, sizeof(info));
        assert(len > 0);
        if (info.AllocationBase != dllBase) break;
        std::cout << "Address: " << std::hex << info.BaseAddress;
        std::cout << " (" << std::hex << info.RegionSize << ") ";
        std::cout << " protect = " << std::hex << info.Protect;
        DWORD oldprotect;
        if (info.Protect == 0) std::cout << ", VirtualProtect skipped" << std::endl;
        else {
            BOOL ok = VirtualProtect(info.BaseAddress, info.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
            std::cout << ", VirtualProtect = " << (ok ? "okay" : "Failed!") << std::endl;
        }
        address = (BYTE*)info.BaseAddress + info.RegionSize;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program on my machine, running Windows 8.1 x64:

```
Address: 77470000 (1000)  protect = 2, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 77471000 (f000)  protect = 0, VirtualProtect skipped
Address: 77480000 (62000)  protect = 20, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 774E2000 (e000)  protect = 0, VirtualProtect skipped
Address: 774F0000 (7e000)  protect = 2, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 7756E000 (2000)  protect = 0, VirtualProtect skipped
Address: 77570000 (1000)  protect = 4, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 77571000 (f000)  protect = 0, VirtualProtect skipped
Address: 77580000 (1000)  protect = 2, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 77581000 (f000)  protect = 0, VirtualProtect skipped
Address: 77590000 (1a000)  protect = 2, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 775AA000 (6000)  protect = 0, VirtualProtect skipped
```

Running it in 64-bit mode:

```
Address: 00007FFC4F870000 (1000)  protect = 2, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 00007FFC4F871000 (112000)  protect = 20, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 00007FFC4F983000 (1000)  protect = 4, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 00007FFC4F984000 (1000)  protect = 8, VirtualProtect = okay
Address: 00007FFC4F985000 (24000)  protect = 2, VirtualProtect = okay
```

Clearly you have a different Windows version so be sure to run this program on your machine to get comparable results.

The conclusion I draw is there is no fundamental reason for this kind of code to fail.  And if it does on your machine then that's likely to be environmental.  With a very obvious candidate to be your anti-malware software, which of course has a great stake in preventing code from messing with kernel32.dll.  I'm running minimal protection on my machine.